# FragmentActivity not showing in second panel

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

Im using a FragmentActivity in my app. While accessing it shows one panel the list is created in a new activity but, when i run in a tablet, two panels are present in it, but refuses to load the second panel.

"ItemDetailFragment" is the FragmentActivty that implements an OnItemClickListener, it was originally type "Fragment" when i created the project.

I am getting two errors, one in ItemListActivity

```
if (mTwoPane) {
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            //ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
            ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
           //The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction 
           //is not applicable for the arguments (int, ItemDetailFragment)
           // Change type of 'fragment' to 'Fragment'
                    .commit();

        } else {
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ListUsers.class);
            detailIntent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            startActivity(detailIntent);
        }
```

and the exact same error in "ItemDetailActivity" with ".add" causing the error

```
 Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID,
                getIntent().getStringExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID));
        ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
                .commit();
```

please give me any suggestion as this is the first time i have worked with "Fragment"s.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the error message you get:

> The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction 
>              is not applicable for the arguments (int, ItemDetailFragment)
>              **Change type of 'fragment' to 'Fragment'**

Have you tried doing what the error message suggest you do?

```
ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment(); // This does not work
Fragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment(); // This works!
```

If you at a later stage need to use methods exclusive to `ItemDetailFragment`, you can always cast `fragment` back to an `ItemDetailFragment`-object. Like this:

```
((ItemDetailFragment) fragment).someMethod();
```

Comment: tried that, it then tells me "Type mismatch: cannot convert from ItemDetailFragment to Fragment" and asks me to change it back. this time the error is on "new ItenDetailFragment();"